# How do I convert date time string with milliseconds to datetime in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to parse a date time string with milliseconds to datetime

```
DateTime.strptime('20190221095838258727','%Y%m%d%H%M%S%6N')
```

If I run the example above in the ruby console (Ruby 2.5.1) I get following error

```
2.5.1 :021 > DateTime.strptime('20190221095838258727','%Y%m%d%H%M%S%6N')
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):21
        1: from (irb):21:in `strptime'
```

According to the [strptime](https://ruby-doc.com/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-_strptime) documentation I am not able to find the allowed format specification so I use the format specification of the `strftime` function as you can see above.

If I leave `%6N` format out the datetime will created successfully

```
2.5.1 :022 > DateTime.strptime('20190221095838258727','%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
 => Thu, 21 Feb 2019 09:58:38 +0000
```

Comment: `t = Time.strptime('20190221095838258727','%Y%m%d%H%M%S%L')`
Returns
`=> 2019-02-21 09:58:38 +0200`
To access the sub-second values
`t.usec`
Returns
`=> 258727`


That's all I got.

The default %N limit is 9 digits

Comment: @Stuart: That works! Thanks for comment. Obviously the format directive `%6N` doesn't work with the `strptime` function.  The only hint in `strptime` documentation is  ". _strptime does not support specification of flags and width unlike strftime." But its not clear which format directives are supported and which not.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I think the docs are a little wanting here...... Not sure if that's what you were looking for and I can post it as an answer @kbisang?

Comment: @Stuart: Your hint was helpful. You can post it as an answer. Feel free. I will also answer my question with some other details soon.